# What is wrong with the code i show you below?

Tags: r, encoding, linear-regression

lm(formula = FinalData$lnm4 ~ FinalData$p + FinalData$y + FinalData$r)

After I run this code, it appears a lot of data without any sense according to what I am looking for:

```
Call:
lm(formula = FinalData$lnm4 ~ FinalData$p + FinalData$y + FinalData$r)

Coefficients:
           (Intercept)  FinalData$p10,63306356  
               9.54087                 0.01583  
FinalData$p10,74021125  FinalData$p10,82104129  
               0.03349                 0.07474  
FinalData$p10,88798243  FinalData$p101,4196822  
               0.05820                 3.51273  
FinalData$p101,8076396  FinalData$p103,9240236  
               3.53359                 3.55015  
FinalData$p106,3340741  FinalData$p107,1237128  
               3.56641                 3.57840  
FinalData$p108,5576766  FinalData$p109,2171368  
               3.58833                 3.59775  
FinalData$p11,03386738  FinalData$p11,22370173  
               0.09703                 0.11883  
FinalData$p11,30381608  FinalData$p11,45076911  
               0.13296                 0.14763  
FinalData$p11,59193264  FinalData$p11,77034236  
               0.17116                 0.19373  
FinalData$p11,84456091  FinalData$p11,96213754  
               0.22370                 0.25253  
FinalData$p111,3493751  FinalData$p111,8503613  
               3.60937                 3.61799  
FinalData$p112,0753737  FinalData$p113,4781937  
               3.61543                 3.62125  
FinalData$p114,1562937  FinalData$p115,3685705  
               3.63077                 3.64434  
 FinalData$p116,001612   FinalData$p116,188103  
               3.66441                 3.67661  
 FinalData$p116,619443  FinalData$p117,2340485  
               3.68500                 3.69480  
  FinalData$p117,76564  FinalData$p118,5900441  
               3.70466                 3.72675  
FinalData$p119,5954106  FinalData$p12,12830659  
               3.75017                 0.26269  
FinalData$p12,28386213  FinalData$p12,35190983  
               0.27750                 0.31064  
FinalData$p12,38677967   FinalData$p12,5634439  
               0.28693                 0.34135  
FinalData$p12,60988329  FinalData$p12,66483924  
               0.37633                 0.40630  
FinalData$p12,72853202  FinalData$p120,0301884  
               0.42785                 3.77398  
FinalData$p120,6344784  FinalData$p13,00411523  
               3.79992                 0.45438  
FinalData$p13,18019519  FinalData$p13,37827786  
               0.46748                 0.48700  
FinalData$p13,57138641  FinalData$p13,67435091  
               0.50251                 0.50395  
FinalData$p13,83951481  FinalData$p14,06117887  
               0.51898                 0.53531  
FinalData$p14,33931047  FinalData$p14,60445552  
               0.55138                 0.58620  
FinalData$p14,94564909  FinalData$p15,29607309  
               0.62017                 0.64942  
FinalData$p15,67514476  FinalData$p15,99577224  
               0.68670                 0.71574  
FinalData$p16,33656771  FinalData$p16,72544192  
               0.75253                 0.80010  
FinalData$p16,99079382  FinalData$p17,30769231  
               0.86388                 0.92109  
FinalData$p17,59319322  FinalData$p18,12999704  
               0.96217                 1.00857  
FinalData$p18,28394266  FinalData$p18,36321107  
               1.10855                 1.05732  
FinalData$p18,73021615  FinalData$p19,56022284  
               1.16586                 1.20729  
FinalData$p19,80146345  FinalData$p20,93995258  
               1.23423                 1.25329  
FinalData$p21,93354453  FinalData$p23,38140597  
               1.26995                 1.31179  
FinalData$p25,10865109  FinalData$p26,95260624  
               1.34382                 1.37411  
FinalData$p28,12539015  FinalData$p29,27990744  
               1.40635                 1.42635  
FinalData$p30,17969279  FinalData$p30,98161694  
               1.45513                 1.48532  
FinalData$p31,79269449   FinalData$p33,0058066  
               1.51955                 1.53414  
FinalData$p34,22296028  FinalData$p35,54947669  
               1.55194                 1.58845  
FinalData$p36,36283195  FinalData$p37,30347092  
               1.62399                 1.67195  
FinalData$p38,48828027  FinalData$p39,70179116  
               1.72242                 1.74746  
FinalData$p40,38833851  FinalData$p41,47428185  
               1.77752                 1.81060  
 FinalData$p42,6869704  FinalData$p44,02833641  
               1.84460                 1.87811  
FinalData$p47,28080014  FinalData$p49,13862087  
               1.91318                 1.94509  
FinalData$p51,33571739  FinalData$p53,84491999  
               1.97684                 2.01949  
FinalData$p55,91629701  FinalData$p57,95885011  
               2.05845                 2.10439  
FinalData$p59,18339846  FinalData$p60,39422725  
               2.13550                 2.17628  
FinalData$p61,35053919  FinalData$p62,97634441  
               2.21202                 2.29296  
FinalData$p64,02985499  FinalData$p64,96213725  
               2.31738                 2.34514  
FinalData$p66,05916559  FinalData$p67,39400506  
               2.37719                 2.40944  
FinalData$p68,04166209  FinalData$p68,25637466  
               2.44860                 2.47585  
FinalData$p69,48459576  FinalData$p70,40403317  
               2.50269                 2.53387  
FinalData$p70,67216992  FinalData$p71,96749183  
               2.55871                 2.59396  
 FinalData$p72,5477276  FinalData$p73,72406082  
               2.62498                 2.66099  
FinalData$p74,59019946  FinalData$p75,89605735  
               2.69005                 2.71746  
FinalData$p76,85387132  FinalData$p77,99397397  
               2.75105                 2.78363  
FinalData$p78,15302901  FinalData$p78,47218214  
               2.82719                 2.86521  
 FinalData$p78,9176321  FinalData$p79,78899495  
               2.88050                 2.91719  
FinalData$p81,02107616  FinalData$p82,21249408  
               2.96313                 2.99994  
FinalData$p83,36302378  FinalData$p84,34062775  
               3.03710                 3.08175  
FinalData$p85,20254512  FinalData$p86,73537558  
               3.12125                 3.15897  
FinalData$p88,48737755  FinalData$p90,50318663  
               3.20909                 3.24438  
 FinalData$p91,8150715  FinalData$p92,72800146  
               3.28486                 3.33032  
FinalData$p94,70553978  FinalData$p96,70318486  
               3.37416                 3.41796  
FinalData$p98,01288082  FinalData$p98,79589178  
               3.45565                 3.48924  
           FinalData$y        FinalData$r10,21  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r10,23        FinalData$r10,48  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r10,64        FinalData$r10,65  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r10,74        FinalData$r10,75  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r10,94        FinalData$r10,98  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r10,99        FinalData$r11,01  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r11,17        FinalData$r11,24  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r11,44        FinalData$r11,46  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r11,53        FinalData$r11,56  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r11,88        FinalData$r11,97  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r11,98        FinalData$r12,23  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r12,35        FinalData$r12,36  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r12,39        FinalData$r12,42  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r12,47        FinalData$r12,51  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r13,02        FinalData$r13,06  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r13,33        FinalData$r13,36  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r13,61        FinalData$r13,62  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r13,94        FinalData$r14,23  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r14,32        FinalData$r14,33  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r14,48        FinalData$r14,59  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r14,78        FinalData$r15,12  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r15,68        FinalData$r15,84  
                    NA                      NA  
      FinalData$r16,28         FinalData$r3,67  
                    NA                      NA  
        FinalData$r3,7         FinalData$r3,72  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r3,76          FinalData$r4,3  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r4,31         FinalData$r4,41  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r4,46         FinalData$r4,65  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r4,75         FinalData$r4,89  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r4,92         FinalData$r4,93  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r5,19         FinalData$r5,28  
                    NA                      NA  
        FinalData$r5,3         FinalData$r5,39  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r5,47         FinalData$r5,48  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r5,49          FinalData$r5,5  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r5,52         FinalData$r5,54  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r5,59          FinalData$r5,6  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r5,64         FinalData$r5,73  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r5,92            FinalData$r6  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r6,11         FinalData$r6,22  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r6,29         FinalData$r6,33  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r6,53         FinalData$r6,54  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r6,55         FinalData$r6,58  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r6,62         FinalData$r6,63  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r6,75         FinalData$r6,78  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r6,81         FinalData$r6,82  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r6,85         FinalData$r6,96  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r7,11         FinalData$r7,18  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r7,24         FinalData$r7,46  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r7,48         FinalData$r7,65  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r7,78         FinalData$r7,81  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r7,88         FinalData$r7,94  
                    NA                      NA  
        FinalData$r8,1         FinalData$r8,21  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r8,23         FinalData$r8,31  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r8,38         FinalData$r8,42  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r8,76         FinalData$r8,84  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r8,86         FinalData$r8,97  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r9,12         FinalData$r9,17  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r9,27         FinalData$r9,29  
                    NA                      NA  
        FinalData$r9,3         FinalData$r9,32  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r9,35         FinalData$r9,37  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r9,46         FinalData$r9,48  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r9,68         FinalData$r9,69  
                    NA                      NA  
        FinalData$r9,7         FinalData$r9,71  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r9,72         FinalData$r9,77  
                    NA                      NA  
       FinalData$r9,98  
                    NA  

> lm(formula = FinalData$lnm4 ~ FinalData$p + FinalData$y + FinalData$r)

Call:
lm(formula = FinalData$lnm4 ~ FinalData$p + FinalData$y + FinalData$r)

Coefficients:
           (Intercept)  
               9.54087  
FinalData$p10,63306356  
               0.01583  
FinalData$p10,74021125  
               0.03349  
FinalData$p10,82104129  
               0.07474  
FinalData$p10,88798243  
               0.05820  
FinalData$p101,4196822  
               3.51273  
FinalData$p101,8076396  
               3.53359  
FinalData$p103,9240236  
               3.55015  
FinalData$p106,3340741  
               3.56641  
FinalData$p107,1237128  
               3.57840  
FinalData$p108,5576766  
               3.58833  
FinalData$p109,2171368  
               3.59775  
FinalData$p11,03386738  
               0.09703  
FinalData$p11,22370173  
               0.11883  
FinalData$p11,30381608  
               0.13296  
FinalData$p11,45076911  
               0.14763  
FinalData$p11,59193264  
               0.17116  
FinalData$p11,77034236  
               0.19373  
FinalData$p11,84456091  
               0.22370  
FinalData$p11,96213754  
               0.25253  
FinalData$p111,3493751  
               3.60937  
FinalData$p111,8503613  
               3.61799  
FinalData$p112,0753737  
               3.61543  
FinalData$p113,4781937  
               3.62125  
FinalData$p114,1562937  
               3.63077  
FinalData$p115,3685705  
               3.64434  
 FinalData$p116,001612  
               3.66441  
 FinalData$p116,188103  
               3.67661  
 FinalData$p116,619443  
               3.68500  
FinalData$p117,2340485  
               3.69480  
  FinalData$p117,76564  
               3.70466  
FinalData$p118,5900441  
               3.72675  
FinalData$p119,5954106  
               3.75017  
FinalData$p12,12830659  
               0.26269  
FinalData$p12,28386213  
               0.27750  
FinalData$p12,35190983  
               0.31064  
FinalData$p12,38677967  
               0.28693  
 FinalData$p12,5634439  
               0.34135  
FinalData$p12,60988329  
               0.37633  
FinalData$p12,66483924  
               0.40630  
FinalData$p12,72853202  
               0.42785  
FinalData$p120,0301884  
               3.77398  
FinalData$p120,6344784  
               3.79992  
FinalData$p13,00411523  
               0.45438  
FinalData$p13,18019519  
               0.46748  
FinalData$p13,37827786  
               0.48700  
FinalData$p13,57138641  
               0.50251  
FinalData$p13,67435091  
               0.50395  
FinalData$p13,83951481  
               0.51898  
FinalData$p14,06117887  
               0.53531  
FinalData$p14,33931047  
               0.55138  
FinalData$p14,60445552  
               0.58620  
FinalData$p14,94564909  
               0.62017  
FinalData$p15,29607309  
               0.64942  
FinalData$p15,67514476  
               0.68670  
FinalData$p15,99577224  
               0.71574  
FinalData$p16,33656771  
               0.75253  
FinalData$p16,72544192  
               0.80010  
FinalData$p16,99079382  
               0.86388  
FinalData$p17,30769231  
               0.92109  
FinalData$p17,59319322  
               0.96217  
FinalData$p18,12999704  
               1.00857  
FinalData$p18,28394266  
               1.10855  
FinalData$p18,36321107  
               1.05732  
FinalData$p18,73021615  
               1.16586  
FinalData$p19,56022284  
               1.20729  
FinalData$p19,80146345  
               1.23423  
FinalData$p20,93995258  
               1.25329  
FinalData$p21,93354453  
               1.26995  
FinalData$p23,38140597  
               1.31179  
FinalData$p25,10865109  
               1.34382  
FinalData$p26,95260624  
               1.37411  
FinalData$p28,12539015  
               1.40635  
FinalData$p29,27990744  
               1.42635  
FinalData$p30,17969279  
               1.45513  
FinalData$p30,98161694  
               1.48532  
FinalData$p31,79269449  
               1.51955  
 FinalData$p33,0058066  
               1.53414  
FinalData$p34,22296028  
               1.55194  
FinalData$p35,54947669  
               1.58845  
FinalData$p36,36283195  
               1.62399  
FinalData$p37,30347092  
               1.67195  
FinalData$p38,48828027  
               1.72242  
FinalData$p39,70179116  
               1.74746  
FinalData$p40,38833851  
               1.77752  
FinalData$p41,47428185  
               1.81060  
 FinalData$p42,6869704  
               1.84460  
FinalData$p44,02833641  
               1.87811  
FinalData$p47,28080014  
               1.91318  
FinalData$p49,13862087  
               1.94509  
FinalData$p51,33571739  
               1.97684  
FinalData$p53,84491999  
               2.01949  
FinalData$p55,91629701  
               2.05845  
FinalData$p57,95885011  
               2.10439  
FinalData$p59,18339846  
               2.13550  
FinalData$p60,39422725  
               2.17628  
FinalData$p61,35053919  
               2.21202  
FinalData$p62,97634441  
               2.29296  
FinalData$p64,02985499  
               2.31738  
FinalData$p64,96213725  
               2.34514  
FinalData$p66,05916559  
               2.37719  
FinalData$p67,39400506  
               2.40944  
FinalData$p68,04166209  
               2.44860  
FinalData$p68,25637466  
               2.47585  
FinalData$p69,48459576  
               2.50269  
FinalData$p70,40403317  
               2.53387  
FinalData$p70,67216992  
               2.55871  
FinalData$p71,96749183  
               2.59396  
 FinalData$p72,5477276  
               2.62498  
FinalData$p73,72406082  
               2.66099  
FinalData$p74,59019946  
               2.69005  
FinalData$p75,89605735  
               2.71746  
FinalData$p76,85387132  
               2.75105  
FinalData$p77,99397397  
               2.78363  
FinalData$p78,15302901  
               2.82719  
FinalData$p78,47218214  
               2.86521  
 FinalData$p78,9176321  
               2.88050  
FinalData$p79,78899495  
               2.91719  
FinalData$p81,02107616  
               2.96313  
FinalData$p82,21249408  
               2.99994  
FinalData$p83,36302378  
               3.03710  
FinalData$p84,34062775  
               3.08175  
FinalData$p85,20254512  
               3.12125  
FinalData$p86,73537558  
               3.15897  
FinalData$p88,48737755  
               3.20909  
FinalData$p90,50318663  
               3.24438  
 FinalData$p91,8150715  
               3.28486  
FinalData$p92,72800146  
               3.33032  
FinalData$p94,70553978  
               3.37416  
FinalData$p96,70318486  
               3.41796  
FinalData$p98,01288082  
               3.45565  
FinalData$p98,79589178  
               3.48924  
           FinalData$y  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r10,21  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r10,23  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r10,48  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r10,64  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r10,65  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r10,74  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r10,75  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r10,94  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r10,98  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r10,99  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r11,01  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r11,17  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r11,24  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r11,44  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r11,46  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r11,53  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r11,56  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r11,88  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r11,97  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r11,98  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r12,23  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r12,35  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r12,36  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r12,39  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r12,42  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r12,47  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r12,51  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r13,02  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r13,06  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r13,33  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r13,36  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r13,61  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r13,62  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r13,94  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r14,23  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r14,32  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r14,33  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r14,48  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r14,59  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r14,78  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r15,12  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r15,68  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r15,84  
                    NA  
      FinalData$r16,28  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r3,67  
                    NA  
        FinalData$r3,7  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r3,72  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r3,76  
                    NA  
        FinalData$r4,3  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r4,31  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r4,41  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r4,46  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r4,65  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r4,75  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r4,89  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r4,92  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r4,93  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r5,19  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r5,28  
                    NA  
        FinalData$r5,3  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r5,39  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r5,47  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r5,48  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r5,49  
                    NA  
        FinalData$r5,5  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r5,52  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r5,54  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r5,59  
                    NA  
        FinalData$r5,6  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r5,64  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r5,73  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r5,92  
                    NA  
          FinalData$r6  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,11  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,22  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,29  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,33  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,53  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,54  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,55  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,58  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,62  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,63  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,75  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,78  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,81  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,82  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,85  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r6,96  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r7,11  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r7,18  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r7,24  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r7,46  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r7,48  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r7,65  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r7,78  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r7,81  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r7,88  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r7,94  
                    NA  
        FinalData$r8,1  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r8,21  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r8,23  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r8,31  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r8,38  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r8,42  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r8,76  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r8,84  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r8,86  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r8,97  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,12  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,17  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,27  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,29  
                    NA  
        FinalData$r9,3  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,32  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,35  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,37  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,46  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,48  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,68  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,69  
                    NA  
        FinalData$r9,7  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,71  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,72  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,77  
                    NA  
       FinalData$r9,98  
                    NA
```

Comment: Hi! the code or output is really long. Can you narrow it down to where you think the error is occurring?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to add as a comment but this appears to be a result of your data being in factor format. If you test your predictor variables structure (e.g. `str(FinalData)`), it will likely say it is a Factor with a large number of levels. For each variable that is a factor, you can quickly convert to numeric type by:

```
FinalData$R <- as.numeric(levels(FinalData$R))[FinalData$R]
```

[Referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information)